# Repeat the rectangular object in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I am new to pygame app development. In my game a rectangular object rotates in pygame window in a squarely manner. But what I want is to add one more rectangular object and do the same thing. My code

```
import pygame
from itertools import cycle
pygame.init() 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300)) 
s_r = screen.get_rect()
player = pygame.Rect((100, 100, 50, 50))
timer = pygame.time.Clock()
speed = 5
up, down, left, right = (0, -speed), (0, speed), (-speed, 0), (speed, 0)

dirs = cycle([up, right, down, left])

dir = next(dirs)

while True:

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        raise

# move player
player.move_ip(dir)
# if it's outside the screen
if not s_r.contains(player):
    # put it back inside
    player.clamp_ip(s_r)
    # and switch to next direction
    dir = next(dirs)

screen.fill(pygame.color.Color('Black'))
pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.color.Color('Grey'), player)

pygame.display.flip()
timer.tick(25)
```

When I added a new player object like `pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.color.Color('Grey'), player2)` the second image is formed but it doesnt rotate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to update the second player's position (at least that's what I think)

The following code is just a quick update of your code, normally you would use lists if you wanted to hold more than two players, but this should work just fine

```
import pygame
from itertools import cycle
pygame.init() 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300)) 
s_r = screen.get_rect()
player = pygame.Rect((100, 100, 50, 50))
player2 = pygame.Rect((200, 100, 50, 50))
timer = pygame.time.Clock()
speed = 5
up, down, left, right = (0, -speed), (0, speed), (-speed, 0), (speed, 0)

dirs1 = cycle([up, right, down, left])
dirs2 = cycle([up, right, down, left])

dir1 = next(dirs1)
dir2 = next(dirs2)

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            raise

    # move player    
    player.move_ip(dir1)
    player2.move_ip(dir2)
    # if it's outside the screen
    if not s_r.contains(player):
    # put it back inside
        player.clamp_ip(s_r)
        # and switch to next direction
        dir1 = next(dirs1)

    if not s_r.contains(player2):
        # put it back inside
        player2.clamp_ip(s_r)
        # and switch to next direction
        dir2 = next(dirs2)

    screen.fill(pygame.color.Color('Black'))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.color.Color('Grey'), player)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.color.Color('Grey'), player2)
    pygame.display.flip()
    timer.tick(25)
```

Comment: ..i didnt understood it ..can you please post the full code

Comment: ..can you post the full code please when i tried it its not working

Comment: please have a look at these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523607/start-event-when-button-is-clicked-with-pygame